# Mustache in Reverse

Tags: ruby, xml, mustache

I'm using mustache (in ruby) to generate an XML document from a hash.

Is there a way for me to generate a hash from the XML document and the mustache template?

Answer (score 0):

Having thought about this for a while I realise it's impossible. There are multiple instances of two original hashes creating the same document with Mustache, so this would never be reasonably viable.

Among many others:

```
doc = {
  "words": [
    "an",
    "aconda"
  ]
}

template = "here's some words: {{#words}}{{.}}{{/words}}"

out = Mustache.render(template,doc)
# => "here's some words: anaconda"

Mustache.reverse(template,out)
# {'words' => ['anaconda']}
```